# I am receiving a huge number when expecting a small binary number

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

```
while playAgain == "d":
    intDec = int(input("\nType in a normal, or decimal, number: "))
    x = intDec
    y = 0

    tot = ""

    while(x>=0):
        y=x%2

        x/=2
        tot+=str(y)
    print("\n", tot[::-1],"\n")
    playAgain = input("What do you want to do? (c, d (anything else to quit)): ")
```

This is part of my code in a bigger project. I have successfully added in the ability to convert binary to decimal. For some reason though, I cannot get this one to work. I have attempted many things, and even edited a few. The `while(x>=0)` is the most logical thing to do, and it gives nothing when I run it. If I change it to a `(x>0)` or a `(x!=0)`, it gives a complete error, which I put at the bottom of the post, but please read on. I have tried `while(x>-1)` which also gives me nothing, just a long wait. Anyone know anything on this? This is the error BTW:

> Type in a normal, or decimal, number:  155
>
> 423-e5323-e1323-e5.2323-e5223-e1223-e39.1223-e58.3223-e66.7123-e35.1123->e360.3123-e621.6023-e3522.1023-e6054.2023-e109.4023-e3208.9913-e54069.1913->e9029.3913-e8148.7813-e63865.1813-e427631.3813-e54372.6713-e6986452.1713->e973905.2713-e4857810.5613-e76157300.1613-e43305700.2613-e7600510.4613->e73310030.8513-e476200606.1513-e53500212.3513-e596010424.6413-e931208482.1413->e872406965.2413-e655802931.5313-e52117148720.1313-e5224386550.2313->e548663111.4313-e96337222.8213-e837645446.1213-e699574390982.3213-

etc.... It goes on for about a hundred lines and ends with a .05.11

The response I was expecting was 10011011 but I got that huge chunk of failure. I would love it if any one was willing to help me. Thank you. :)

Comment: The `x>=0` creates an infinite loop. `x` will never go negative.

Comment: Ohh, that made a spark in my mind. :) thanks for clearing things up.

Comment: I tried your idea, and added the code, `If(x==0): break` HOWEVER, it gave me the same error that I posted above.

Comment: The tittle `I honestly don't know why I am getting this error` won't help anybody else with the same problem come to this post. I suggest using something more descriptive.

Comment: In real life math you will never get down to zero if you devide a positive number by 2 again and again. In computers there's a limited accuracy for floating point numbers and at some point the result will be so near to 0 that it will actually be consideres 0. That is what stops your loop, after more iterations than you have expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Built-in function is available for this

```
bin(155)  #10011011
```

You have to use floor division to get the integral part of the quotient.
And you have to use `x>0` to avoid infinite loop.

Edited:

```
while playAgain == "d":
    intDec = int(input("\nType in a normal, or decimal, number: "))

    x = intDec
    y = 0

    tot = ''

    while(x>0):
        y=x%2
        x//=2
        print(y)
        tot+=str(y)
    print("\n",tot[::-1],"\n")
    playAgain = input("What do you want to do? (c, d (anything else to quit)): ")
```

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I am just exercising my skills, and problem solving. I wondered if I could create a replica of the original function. Thanks for the comment tho! <3

Comment: Ahhh, I understand now. Thank you for your effort and kindness. :) Have a wonderful day, and thank you for clearing things up. You can do (x>=0), but you have to break the loop. At one point, the variable, tot, has to process the 'x=0' so I have to keep it that way. The way to make it work is to break the loop after it processes it. Thank you, yet again :).